# Functions to take numbers from text with time, and total them up, in a list, per person

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to take the duration of trainings, that have "Duration: x Hours x Minutes" And compile it into a total training time per person, based on a list of people to link the times to. I'm not great at using complex functions, and any help would be much appreciated. Even better if there's a way to find the difference between minutes and hours, and add them accordingly, as some sets of data only have minutes, or only have "1 Hour."

I tried to use
`=SUMIF('Training Times'!A2:A,A2,regexextract('Training Times'!B2:B,[0-9]+))`
and expected it to use the list of multiple names, where there are multiple cases of each name, on the first page, compare it to the name beside it on the second page, take the numbers from the times on the first page, add them up, and print the total of the time. I only get a #ERROR "Formula Parse Error" code, when running this function.

My test sheet, with a wide range of names on the first page, and a select number of names on the second page. There will be 3 sets of names, on different sheets that this formula will hopefully work for. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRkboVbxO9vgZikBVUm-iWPG9o_2HlyrLBgQLuTSdeA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this in two steps in order to simplify formulas readability.

**Add a new column that will hold extracted timings in minutes:**

This can be done by this formula:
`=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT($B2, "(\d+) ?[hH]our"), 0) * 60 + IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT($B2, "(\d+) ?[mM]inute"), 0)`

Basically speaking, the formula search for digits that followed by "hour" or "Hour", and similar minutes. It also fallbacks to 0 if the pattern doesn't match. Hours multiplied by 60 in order to convert to minutes.

**Compute sum per name**

Now, it is possible to simply calculate sum for each individual name and convert it to the duration format.

Assuming that the column "C" now have extracted minutes from the first step, the formula will be:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(($A2:$A=$D2) * $C2:$C)) / 24 / 60`

This formula is basically multiplies two ranges. The first will a zeros when name doesn't match and ones when it matches. The second will contains minutes extract from the first step. This way multiplying to zero will just nullify the result when the name doesn't match.

Finally, it divide minutes by 24 and 60 in order to convert minutes to the share of the day, e.g whole day = 1.

Here is an example of how it might look like in the Spreadsheet:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
    {A2:A,IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"(?i)(\d+) ?hours?"))/24+
          IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"(?i)(\d+) ?min(?:ute)?s?"))/1440},
    "select Col1, sum(Col2)
     where Col1<>'' 
     group by Col1 
     label Col1 'Name', sum(Col2) 'Total Time'
     format sum(Col2) 'hh:mm'"))
```

### Update

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(A2:A="",,
     IFNA(
       VLOOKUP(
         A2:A,
         QUERY(
           {'Training Times'!A2:A,
             IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT('Training Times'!B2:B,"(?i)(\d+) ?hours?"))/24+
             IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT('Training Times'!B2:B,"(?i)(\d+) ?min(?:ute)?s?"))/1440},
           "select Col1, sum(Col2)
            group by Col1"),
         2,),
       0)))
```

Comment: That answer is great, however for a different use case from mine, I need it to only look through the names on the second page, and print beside those names(Or different spot I can specify, preferable as a Copy/Paste down the line.).

Comment: you can just add a VLOOKUP. See updated answer.